# name 'instance' is not defined in my __init__ ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

Why he does not recognize me the instance of my views "access" in my ModelForm ?

I have this error : `name 'instance' is not defined`

my forms :

```
class ReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        super (ReplyForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['question'].queryset = Question.objects.get(page=instance)

    class Meta:
        model = Reply
```

and my views.py :

```
def access(request, instance):
    length_questions = len(questions)
    ReplyFormSet = modelformset_factory(model=Reply, form=ReplyForm, extra=length_questions, can_delete=True)
    formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            new_instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for new_instance in new_instances:
                new_instance.user = logged_user
                new_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/baseVisite/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('polls/error.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset=Reply.objects.none())
    return render_to_response('polls/access.html', {
 'formset': formset,
 'questions':questions,
 'logged_user':logged_user,
 'numPages' : numPages
 })
```

Edit url :

```
url(r'^access/(?P<instance>[0-9]+)/$', views.access),
```

Comment: Well, where do you think that it is defined?

Comment: Early in my access function but I do not know how to make that my ModelForm he recognizes

Comment: In my forms this line doesn't work : `self.fields['question'].queryset = Question.objects.get(page=instance)` because instance is not define but how I can define?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `instance` is only defined in your `view`.
If you want to use it in `__init__` method of your `Form` you have to pass it explicitly.

I have not experience with `modelformset_factory`, but without that it could look like this:

Form:

```
class ReplyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.pop('instance')
        super (ReplyForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['question'].queryset = Question.objects.get(page=instance)

    class Meta:
        model = Reply
```

View:

```
def access(request, instance):
    ...
    # explicitly pass instance as keyword argument to ReplyForm
    form  = ReplyForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
    ...
```

Comment: It does not recognize better "instance" ;) thanks anyway